# Mouse over events not fired when using jQuery ui.sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI Sortables to sort items between lists and drag / drop items from one list to the other.

The lists are collapsible with header DIVs that control the expand / collapse operations. I would like to have the lists expand automatically when hovering over their title DIVs with the mouse, but only when I'm currently sorting a list.

The problem is that when currently sorting (when I'm currently dragging a list item), mouseover / mouseout events do not seem to be firing for any object on the page.

Anyone has any idea why this happens / how to work around this?

The general layout:

```
<div class="category">
  <div class="title">title</div>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
     ....
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="category">
  ...
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have right now for your jQuery code?

Comment: Do you have an example of your workaround?

Comment: Use the over event of the droppable functionality of jquery ui to handle the mouseover event and to expand the list.

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over

```
$( ".title" ).droppable({
  over: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).next().show(); # show ul.sortable
  }  
})
```

need jquery-ui droppable, of course

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is a bug in the latest official JQuery 1.3 release.  Get the [latest trunk release](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk) to fix it.

This was related to another question I answered regarding start and update events not working either: [jQuery Sortable callbacks not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466464/jquery-sortable-callbacks-not-working#466566)

Comment: I'm not sure that you understood my problem. Anyway, I ended up working around the issue for which I needed mouseover/out fired.