# jQuery Sortable callbacks not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using the [Sortable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable) component of [jQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com/). The callbacks don't seem to work at all, even with this minimalistic test:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#outer").sortable({
        start: function (e, ui) {
            alert("started");
        },
        update: function (e, ui) {
            alert("updated");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<ul id="outer">
<li>apple</li>
<li>orange</li>
</ul>
```

I get none of the alerts when I reorder these elements.

Is my usage correct or am I perhaps misreading the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable/sortable#options)?

> start Function(Event, ui)
>
> Function that gets called when sorting starts.

Comment: What does firebug (or your preferred javascript debugger) say? I got it working with jQuery 1.3 and the current jQuery UI (personalized: core, draggable, sortable), version 1.6rc5.

Comment: I'm on Firefox and I get absolutely no errors/warnings. It's just dead silent. However, sorting works as expected. It's just the callbacks that don't seem to work. I'm trying to avoid digging into jQuery UI code :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the .sortable() is having some technical difficulties according to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/8be6c23bf57b3199).  You may need to use SVN to download the [latest trunk release](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk) to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this problem by including two versions of jquery simultaneously. Check it out here: http://gist.github.com/59757

Hope it helps!