# jQuery sortable: How to check if a sorting event is fired?

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table that is sortable using the jQuery sortable plugin-in:

```
$("#sortableinputs").sortable();
```

I want to run a code when this event fires (for example a user drags and drops rows of a table in order to reorder it). How can I do this?

I am using like:

```
If (sortable()) {
//check if running

}
```

But it's not working. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: see the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466464/jquery-sortable-callbacks-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stop event on sortable :

```
$( ".sortableinputs" ).sortable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    //your code here 
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Documents, you can use start event of sortable.  [Sortable : start](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start)

```
$( "#sortableinputs" ).sortable({
  start: function( event, ui ) {
 alert('here you put the code');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the .sortable() is having some technical difficulties according to this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-dev/i-bCO_V7MZk).